# Rails / MySQL: How to query for a record by its full 'created_at' timestamp?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I want to be able to find a `User` record by its `created_at` timestamp (which in this case is: `2020-08-07 11:30:28.5934908`).

But the result is this:

```
User.where(created_at: '2020-08-07 11:30:28.5934908').first
=> nil
```

The reason that this (existing) User record is not found seems to become evident in the MySQL query that Rails generated:

`` User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`created_at` = '2020-08-07 11:30:28.593490' ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1 ``

...where for some reason the last digit `8` is dropped from the timestamp `2020-08-07 11:30:28.5934908` used in the MySQL query.

What is the problem here? Does Rails shorten the timestamp in the query? Or does MySQL do this? How do I solve this?

Comment: MySQL supports timestamps with only a [microsecond precision](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fractional-seconds.html) (6 digits after the decimal point) but your query specifies 7 digits (a precision of hundreds of nanoseconds). Are you sure that the timestamp in the query is correct? What is the definition of the `created_at` column in MySQL?

Comment: @BoraMa - You are right, the MySQL table shows a ```datetime(6)``` definition. And the 7th digit used in my query came from a conversion like ```User.first.created_at.to_f```. What would be the correct way to convert a ```datetime``` into its precise ```float``` (number of seconds), if not ```.created_at.to_f```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments I think that the main problem is in the conversion of the microseconds-precise time to Float. Float (even though in ruby internally a Double) does not have enough accuracy to fully represent all dates / times with microseconds precision, as is [documented in the Time class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Time.html#method-i-to_f) (although they speak about “nanoseconds”, interestingly). Such conversion then only tries to find the nearest possible representation in Float. Rounding the resulting float number back to 6 digits may work but I’m not sure it’s guaranteed to always work…

Suppose that the real time stored in DB is `2020-08-07 11:30:28.593491`. As you’ve noticed, this converts to Float imprecisely:

```rb
>> Time.parse('2020-08-07 11:30:28.593491').to_f
=> 1596792628.5934908
```

The guaranteed method would be to use a [Rational number](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Rational.html) instead, i.e. [`to_r`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Time.html#method-i-to_r):

```rb
>> Time.parse('2020-08-07 11:30:28.593491').to_r
=> (1596792628593491/1000000)
```

To reconstruct the Time back from the rational number, you can use `Time.at`:

```rb
>> Time.at(Rational(1596792628593491, 1000000)).usec
=> 593491
```

Note that the microseconds are fully preserved here.

So, storing a `created_at` time precisely and using it later to search for a record involves using a Rational number variable instead of Float:

```rb
>> user_created_at = User.first.created_at.to_r
=> (1596792628593491/1000000)

>> User.where(created_at: Time.at(user_created_at)).first == User.first
=> true
```

An alternative approach might be to store both the integer seconds since Epoch (`User.first.created_at.to_i`) and the nanoseconds fraction (`User.first.created_at.usec`) separately in two variables. They can be the used in [`Time.at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Time.html#method-c-at), too, to reconstruct the time back.

As a sidenote, this has also been discussed in a [Rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33715) with a similar conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer to your question rather a workaround of sorts. You could query the `created_at` column in some very small time delta like this.

```
User.where(created_at: '2020-08-07 11:30:28.593490'...'2020-08-07 11:30:28.593491')
```

Answer (score 0):

As per @BoraMa's comment (thanks!), the MySQL `created_at` timestamp must have 6 digits only. Thus, the working query would look like this:

```
User.where(created_at: '2020-08-07 11:30:28.5934908'.round(6)).first
```